# Создать синоним [protobuf] на метку [google-protobuf]

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Появился один вопрос с меткой [google-protobuf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-protobuf). Смысла в слове "google" тут столько же, сколько было бы в метках google-android или apple-ios. Поэтому нужно создать синоним [protobuf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protobuf)